# color not working with big FloatBuffer with formatting X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A,X,Y,Z,R,

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my Android app with OpenGL es, I want to draw lines with colors using big FloatBuffers where I stuff everything in, coordinates together with color, for better performance. I succeed in drawing the lines on the correct coordinates, but the color remains black. I started off with the example from http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started. The only difference (that I can see), is that they use triangles, where I use lines. So my FloatBuffers have the formatting (X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A, X,Y,Z, R,G,B,A, X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A,... and so one. Each line has only one color, so the color repeat itself for the start- and endpoint (with 4 floats out of 14 being redundant, which I don't care about).
This is the relevant code from my Renderer class:

```
private void drawStuff()
{
    int mPositionDataSize = 3;
    int mColorDataSize = 4;
    int mColorOffset = 3 ;

    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position");
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");

    //1. vertex positions:
    thisBuffer.getVertexFloatBuffers().position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, 
                                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 
                                    28, thisBuffer.getVertexFloatBuffers() );
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    //2. colors:
    thisBuffer.getVertexFloatBuffers().position(mColorOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, mColorDataSize, 
                                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 
                                    28, thisBuffer.getVertexFloatBuffers()) ;
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

    // 3. Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, thisMVPmatrix, 0);

    // 4. Draw the lines
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, thisBuffer.getNrOfVerteces());
}
```

Ideas, anyone?

Edit: My shaders are defined and compiled in my onSurfaceCreated method:

```
    final String vertexShaderPerLayer =
    "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.

  + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
  + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"     // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.

  + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

  + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our vertex shader.
  + "{                              \n"
  + "   v_Color = a_Color;          \n"     // Pass the color through to the fragment shader.
                                            // It will be interpolated across the triangle.
  + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"     // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
  + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in
  + "}                              \n";    // normalized screen coordinates.

int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
// Pass in the shader source.
GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShaderPerLayer);


// Compile the shader.
GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

// Get the compilation status.
final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

// FRAGMENTSHADER
final String fragmentShaderPerLayer =
        "precision mediump float;       \n"     // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a
                                                // precision in the fragment shader.
      + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the
                                                // triangle per fragment.
      + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our fragment shader.
      + "{                              \n"
      + "   gl_FragColor = v_Color;     \n"     // Pass the color directly through the pipeline.
      + "}                              \n";
int fragmentShaderHandlePerLayer = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// Pass in the shader source.
GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandlePerLayer, fragmentShaderPerLayer);

// Compile the shader.
GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandlePerLayer);

// PROGRAM STUFF
mProgramHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

// Bind the vertex shader to the program.
GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramHandle, vertexShaderHandle);

// Bind the fragment shader to the program.
GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramHandle, fragmentShaderHandlePerLayer);

// Bind attributes
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, 0, "a_Position");
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, 1, "a_Color");

// Link the two shaders together into a program.
GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgramHandle);
```

Comment: This all looks good. Shader issue maybe? Post just the relevant shader code for both, vertex and fragment shaders.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the vertex and fragment shaders. Thanks for looking into it, I'm stuck.

Comment: Still all looks good. try pinpointing the issue: First try setting a manual colour in vertex shader v_Color = vec4(1.0...) or something and see if you can see the correct output colour on your shape. If you can your issue seems to be in the data your shaders receive. In that case try logging some colour values from your buffer by accessing thisBuffer.getVertexFloatBuffers() after you set the position to mColorOffset.

Comment: Alright! The vertex shader is not the problem. I have changed the v_color=vec4(...), and now all my lines have that color. So that leaves my beloved Floatbuffer. I'm trying to check my floatbuffer in the debugger. One line with 2 verteces and 2 colors is displayed as an array with length 56 (4 bytes per float * 14 floats) with integer values (between -128 and +128, it seems?). So now I have to figure out how to interpret these values so that I can check that they hold correct values. But I think I can work this out (with a little headache). Thanks!!

Comment: Wait what? integer values (between -128 and +128, it seems?)?! The colour components should be floats in range [.0, 1.0]. If your result is +-128 then your colours are probably unsigned bytes [0, 255] and all you need to do is set GLES20.GL_FLOAT to GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE but if this is true then your stride is wrong: It should be 3*sizeof(float)+4*sizeof(byte)

Comment: no, my colors are not bytes, they are floats, and they are stored like floats in my Bytebuffer. But if I look at my Bytebuffer in the debugger, an array of length 56 is shown. It's an array of bytes, but since a float is 4 bytes, 4 parts of the array are one float. So it's just the debugger that is showing my floats as bytes, which makes it kinda hard to figure out if they are correct.

Comment: Well, if they are not zero they can only be negative to display black. Try using an absolute value in the shader to check that or even make a condition if the colour components are not zero output some fixed colour.

Comment: And can you check what is your mColorHandle ID

Comment: They are not all zero or negative. But I'm going to change my color system. The colors are just RGBA, so unsigned bytes suffice. Then I'll set it GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTES like you said, and use a different stride (3*4+4*1=16), and then it will be much easier to check if the values in the Bytebuffer are correct. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Got it! mColorHandle is always -1. So I rechecked the code, and I used `mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");` instead of `mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's an error in the code.

```
mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");
```

should be:

```
mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");
```